# To unblock script windows powershell

Tags: powershell, window

can anyone help me?

I have use script windows powershell,
But now i want to unblock the script.
I have been trying to follow the instructions but still cant.
I want this is my directroy C:\scripts-windows-setting\remove-onedrive.ps1
Thats i want to unblock

I got the script from github: https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10

Comment: What do you mean by "unblock the script"? Are you trying to run `Unblock-File`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yeah that's what i mean

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i hava been try this but still cant `PS> ls -Recurse C:\scripts-windows-setting\remove-onedrive.ps1 | Unblock-File`,and this PS> ls -Recurse remove-onedrive.ps1 | Unblock-File`

Comment: And what's the problem/question? Are you unsure how to run it against _every_ file in the directory? Or are you running it and seeing errors? Or are you running it and still having trouble running the scripts or importing the module afterwards? Please don't make us guess...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've run the script and it's running fine but i want to make the script disable

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what does that means. What behavior are you looking for that you are not currently getting?

Comment: Mathias is ***very*** kindly trying to guide you through providing the information needed to answer your question. Please help him by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Imagine you were asking a co-worker in the next cube this question - what would they need to help you? what questions do you think they would ask you? In short, provide enough information to help the community answer you without playing 20 questions.

Comment: right-click the downloaded zip file. Go Properties and unblock the file. Then unzip and use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.